# Is there a way to delete punctuation except when preceding certain characters?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, match

More specifically, I want to delete all periods in a column of strings, except when preceded by a number. I have experimented with looping through each string, but this is complicated by the need to have this in a function. What I have now is a "look around" for "not preceded by" from stringr, but it throws a 'Invalid regexp' error:

```
df <- data.frame(c("2.3 to 11.1 on N. Side Ave.", "MP 1.25-4.00 Main St."),
c("12-34", "23-45"))
colnames(df) <- c("ADDR", "NUM")

f.Addr <- function(ADDRESS, NUMBER) {
  ADDRESS <- gsub("(?<![:digit:])[.]", " ", ADDRESS)
  df <- data.frame(NUMBER, ADDRESS)}

df <- f.Addr(df$ADDR, df$NUM)
df
```

Desired output:
ADDR   NUM
1 2.3 to 11.1 on N  Side Ave  12-34
2       MP 1.25-4.00 Main St  23-45

In Python, I think I could use something like "[^0:9][.]" to match. Maybe use parenthesis for R?

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Regex is basically the same in python and R. (R sometimes requires you to escape your backslashes...)

Comment: Did you try `gsub("(?<!\\d)[.]", " ", ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: `gsub("(\\D)\\.", "\\1", df$ADDR)` can use `\\D` as the negation of `\\d` this is the same in python and R.

Comment: `gsub("(?<=\\D)[.]", "", ADDRESS, perl = TRUE)` will also work

Comment: Terrific. All those solutions work. Thanks.